# How to restore deleted startup applications

Tags: startup, system-settings, startup-applications

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 I have accidentally remove some of my startup applications from the "Startup Applications Preferences" GUI, and I don't know what they were, is there a log somewhere which will tell me which ones I removed? Or a way of restoring them?

I read [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1451122) that I could restore them by copying all the entries here:

```
/etc/xdg/autostart/
```

To here:

```
~/.config/autostart
```

Would that work? Or would that still not restore the deleted ones?

These are the ones which I have left:

[image: Startup Applications Preferences]

Comment: "/etc/xdg/autostart/" hold the -default- ones. That does not mean all the ones you deleted: the start up programs you deleted that are not default are not in "/etc/xdg/autostart/". Only thing you can rely on is a backup you made. Someone else can not even list his/her startup programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very simple: restore from your last back-up the directory `/home/szUserName/.config/autostart/*`  where `szUserName` is your actual user name.

For more information on back-ups, please read the following Q&A: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc).

You're *definitely* user type 4!  **;-) >:-)**

Answer (score -1):

1. Open doom'day Terminal by <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+any function key up to <kbd>F7</kbd>.
2. Install `trash-cli` tool.
3. Head over to the `autostart` directory.
4. Run:

   ```
   sudo trash-restore
   ```
5. Restore all your deleted autostart files one by one. If you have deleted them permanently, then there is no way coming back, but if you just moved them to trash, then it will help.

Comment: What is a doom'day Terminal, do you mean a console/terminal? If so, shouldn't that be Ctrl+Alt+F1-F7? Alt+F5 just "unmaximises" the current window.